# GTK+, how to update widgets into mainloop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, gtk

My program work with 2 threads (boost::thread) and, of course, 1 mainloop.
The problem is that I currently update 2 widgets at the end of each threads, and thoses updates sometime provoke segmentations faults.

I use the function "gtk_widget_queue_draw" to update widgets into my threads.

I saw somewhere on the web that we must update all of our widgets into the main loop and never into threads, so my question is simple, how do I do that ?

With signals maybe ?

I already tried with the fundtion "g_idle_add" but it don't work either.
It seems that I can also use gtk_thread_enter and gtk_thread_leave but thoses two functions are deprecated.

Thanks

Edit: I almost forgot; if I want to update manually my widgets, it's because they don't updates automatically (and one of thoses widgets is a chart drawn with cairo)

"g_idle_add" seem to be the good way to do that, but it ends up with segmentation fault too.
Here is the way I implemented this:

In my thread:

```
g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc)update_label_monitor_cpu, &string_cpu);
```

And the function itself:

```
void update_label_monitor_cpu(std::string *str)
{
    std::string tmp = *str;
    gtk_label_set_label(GTK_LABEL(label_monitor_cpu), (gchar*)tmp.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g_idle_add()` is the correct way to do this. You get a segmentation fault because your strings go out of scope, and are destroyed, before the idle callback ever runs. You'll need to manually manage the memory for the strings in your idle callback; for instance, using `g_strdup()` and `g_free()`.

Comment: (sorry for my late response)
It was exactly that, thank you !